# Spinner - Resource From A String Array

Tags: android

I have 2 spinners on my app, one gets it's values from strings.xml and the other gets it's values from a string array built in java.  The latter isn't working as it should.  When I click on the spinner the dropdown shows all the available options but picking one doesn't select it and I am not sure why.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,clientNames);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    clientsSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> csAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.months_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    csAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    monthsSpinner.setAdapter(csAdapter);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to load the parameters from resources this way:

```
String[] parameters = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months_array);
```

and then create the Adapter as you did with the first one

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> csAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parameters );
csAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
monthsSpinner.setAdapter(csAdapter);
```